# Утечки памяти после выполнения программы

Tags: c++, c, утечка-памяти

Недавно заметил одну особенность. Связанную с памятью, как статической так и динамической. После того как запускаю проект несколько раз, все равно какой сложности там идут операции, компьютер начинает проседать по RAM. Как с этим можно бороться и как перебарывать такие проблемы. А то каждые пол часа Mem Reduct'ом чищу RAM.

P.S. все динамическое выгружаю.

Comment: Используйте язык со сборщиком мусора тогда по завершении программы он будет очищать память

Comment: @zenden2k "я пишу на плюсах, написал программу, надо сдавать, но память течет, как отследить проблему?" - "ПЕРЕПИШИ НА ЯЗЫКЕ С GC"

Comment: ОС какая? Винда?

Comment: Может не утечки, а дефрагментация? Может быть у вас память интенсивно выделяется мелкими блоками? Эффект "рассасывается" через небольшое время?

Answer (score 4):

Когда процесс завершает свою работу, ОС в любом случае утилизирует всю его память, независимо от того, как программа была написана. Поэтому, варианта есть только два:

1. На самом деле ваша программа никогда не останавливается
2. Проблема вообще не в вашей программе

Проверить пункт 1 очень просто - запустите диспетчер задач и поищите вашу программу в списке процессов. Если ее там нет - значит, проблема не в ней.

Кстати, в любом случае полезно поискать аномалии в этом списке. Как правило, хорошо видно, какая из программ отжирает память. Обычно это браузеры, хотя и IDE тоже такое дело любят.

Comment: в том то и дело, тестировал и смотрел что происходит, закрывал браузер. либо это есть IDE чего я не видел, либо ...

Comment: Диспетчер задач умеет показывать потребляемую процессами память. Воспользуйтесь им, не надо гадать на кофейной гуще.

Answer (score 0):

Если ты не используешь WinApi для выделения памяти в чужих процессах и работаешь не в DOS, где были доступны дальние указатели, то память будет освобождена системой при завершении программы.

Comment: «используешь WinApi для выделения памяти в чужих процессах». Ого!